# Running VBA on all the sheets

Tags: vba, excel

My knowledge for VBA is close to null, but I've found a code that I could change to reach my purpose. The only thing now is that this code is running only for the worksheet named "test" and I need to run this code for all the worksheets on the same file.

Thank you very much.

```
Sub MyCopyPasteValues()
' CopyPasteValus Macro
' Macro to hard code last weeks data.

Dim i As Byte, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("test")

For y = 7 To 24

    For i = 3 To 4

        If ws.Cells(y, 2).Value < ws.Range("K" & 7).Value Then

            ws.Cells(y, i).Value = ws.Cells(y, i).Value

        End If

    Next i

Next y

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
Sub MyCopyPasteValues() ' CopyPasteValus Macro ' Macro to hard code last weeks data.
Dim i As Byte, ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    For y = 7 To 24
        For i = 3 To 4
            If ws.Cells(y, 2).Value < ws.Range("K" & 7).Value Then
                ws.Cells(y, i).Value = ws.Cells(y, i).Value
            End If
        Next i
    Next y
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Go with @Ralph's - his includes better declarations etc. and he even uses `Next ws` which makes reading the code later that much easier. (My code is lazy)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyCopyPasteValues()
' CopyPasteValus Macro
' Macro to hard code last weeks data.

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Y As Long, i As Long

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Y = 7 To 24
        For i = 3 To 4
            If ws.Cells(Y, 2).Value < ws.Range("K7").Value Then
                ws.Cells(Y, i).Value = ws.Cells(Y, i).Value
            End If
        Next i
    Next Y
Next ws

End Sub
```